# Update Specific value of specific XML tag using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've following XML

```
<Account>
   <account>
        <userid>4</userid>
        <iban>TR600061200000012990025478</iban>
        <accountno>0000012990025478</accountno>
        <money>
        </money>
        <identityno>78546985462</identityno>
        <birthdate>28.05.1986</birthdate>
        <adress>İstanbul/Üsküdar</adress>
    </account>
</Account>
```

I want to update value of `money` tag on button click. Here is what I've tried

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
var node = doc.Descendants("Account").FirstOrDefault(personDetail => personDetail.Element("money").Value==txt.Text);
node.SetElementValue("money", this.txt.Text);
doc.Save(@"XMLFile1.xml");
```

Comment: Please review and modify your question. Use simple words to make your question clear.

Comment: When asking question on StackOverFlow please try to put everything that you have tried till now and clearly mention what you are using to do that so. Please have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `XDocument` to parse the xml string. Find the money `XElement` and update his value.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");

    var result = doc.Root.Descendants("money").FirstOrDefault();

    if (result == null)
       return;

    result.Value = txt.Text;
    doc.Save(@"XMLFile1.xml"); 

}
```

**EDIT**

Check [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5TKeCN)

Comment: @A.Gecu I edit you dotNetFiddle to see it with string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your condition

```
personDetail => personDetail.Element("money").Value==txt.Text
```

This will only find nodes where the text is already equal to the text you want to apply.

Once you change the text in the textbox, there will not be a node matching this criteria any longer - and the new text will not be applied.

It will start getting better if you use `!=` in the condition.